# Convergence in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have two questions. Let $V$ be a subspace of finite-dimensional vector space $U$. Suppose $u_k\to u_0$ in $U$ as $k\to\infty$.

First, for any $f\in U'$, is it true that $f(u_k)\to f(u_0)$? If so, why is this true?

Second, does $u_k\to u_0$ in $U$ imply that $[u_k]\to[u_0]$ in $U/V$ as $k\to\infty$ where the norm of $U/V$ is induced by the norm of $U$ by $\vert\vert[u]\vert\vert=\inf\{\vert\vert v\vert\vert :v\in [u]\}$ where $[u]\in U/V$ and $u\in U$?

Note: $U'$ denotes the dual space of $U$ (space of linear functionals)

Comment: Does $U'$ denotes the topological dual of $U$, i.e. the space of *continuous* linear functions on $U$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes indeed it does.

Comment: @mathim1881 It looks like you missed the word "continuous" in TheSilverDoe's comment. What you are asking is equivalent to the functionals in $U'$ being continuous, so if you are assuming they are continuous, the first question is trivial. It sounds like you mean $U'$ is the *algebraic* dual, i.e. the vector space of linear functionals (continuous or not).

Comment: @user837206 Hey, yes I mean the algebraic dual, meaning the vector space of linear functionals. I am curious if the answer is still yes for both considering these can be continuous or not continuous.

Comment: @mathim1881 The answer is yes: the algebraic and topological duals coincide in finite dimensions, i.e. every linear functional on a finite dimensional space (indeed, any linear map with finite-dimensional domain) is automatically continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of both questios is yes. The first by the continuity of linear functionals and the second by continity of the canonical proyection $P:U\to U/V$, note that every linear function between finite dimensional vector spaces is continuous in any norms.

Comment: Thanks, if I am speaking about the algebraic dual which is the vector space of linear functionals, continuous or not, is the answer still yes for both?

Comment: In finite dimension every linear functional is continuous, hence the answer is yes.